# How to store loops with diferent row-length for each loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am using `pageviews` to collect some data for different countries. I would like to store all the results in a nice loop in one shot. The issue is that the data for each country have different length and I find hard to store it.

What I have is:

```
library("pageviews")

lang = c("it.wikipedia", "de.wikipedia", "fr.wikipedia", "es.wikipedia")

# each country has a different length: it =1134, de = 1908, fr=1803, es=1205
# you can check it here
eg = article_pageviews(project = lang[1], article = "ECB", platform = "all", user_type = "user", start = "2015100100", end = today(), reformat = TRUE, granularity = "daily")

x = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 4247, ncol = 8), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(x) = names(eg)

for (i in 1:length(lang)) {
  for(i in d){

x[, ] = article_pageviews(project = lang[i], article = "ECB", platform = "all", user_type = "user", start = "2015100100", end = today(), reformat = TRUE, granularity = "daily")
  }
}

# how to structure x?
```

I am not sure how to structure `x` or the loop in such a way that each result loads after the end of the previous one. For example, `lang[1]` would store from row 1:1134, `lang[2]` 1134+1:1134+1+1908, etc...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why not set `x <- list()`, and then use `do.call()` to bind the lists as a `data.frame`? This will give you exactly what you need.

Comment: @Serkan I tried before `for (i in 1:length(lang)) {

x[i] = article_pageviews(project = lang[i], article = "ECB", platform = "all", user_type = "user", start = "2015100100", end = today(), reformat = TRUE, granularity = "daily")
  }` with `x` being an empty least. The issue I had with that is that it did not get the columns. I just got the first column.

Comment: See my answer, we can always change it so it fits your needs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
library("pageviews")

lang = c("it.wikipedia", "de.wikipedia", "fr.wikipedia", "es.wikipedia")

x <- list()

for (i in 1:length(lang)) {
   
        
        x[[i]]= article_pageviews(
            project = lang[i], 
            article = "ECB",
            platform = "all", 
            user_type = "user",
            start = Sys.Date() - 10, 
            end = Sys.Date(), 
            reformat = TRUE, 
            granularity = "daily")
    
}


do.call(
    rbind, x
)
```

It gives the following output,

```
     project language article     access agent granularity       date views
1  wikipedia       it     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-11     1
2  wikipedia       it     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-13     0
3  wikipedia       it     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-15     0
4  wikipedia       it     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-16     1
5  wikipedia       it     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-18     0
6  wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-10     5
7  wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-11     4
8  wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-12     1
9  wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-13     0
10 wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-14     1
11 wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-15     1
12 wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-16     8
13 wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-17     2
14 wikipedia       de     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-18     2
15 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-09     3
16 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-10     1
17 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-11     1
18 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-12     3
19 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-14     1
20 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-15     2
21 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-16     2
22 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-17     3
23 wikipedia       fr     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-18     1
24 wikipedia       es     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-09     0
25 wikipedia       es     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-10     1
26 wikipedia       es     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-14     0
27 wikipedia       es     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-15     1
28 wikipedia       es     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-17     1
29 wikipedia       es     ECB all-access  user       daily 2021-03-18     0
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for, then? Please note that when working with  `list` you nee to add `[[` and `]]`. The loop will store it sequentially along your specified argument, in this case it is the contents of `lang`. Im happy it worked for you!

Best.

Comment: yes it is exactly what I was looking for. One more question: let's assume that now I also have n elements in `article`. So the loops goes first per country `i` and then by article `j`. How shall I change `[[i]]` to store everything?

Comment: Then it is a nested `for loop` and `list`, which is something along the lines of `x <- list(list())`, where the outer `list` your country, and inner `list` is the article. You'll have to create as many inner `lists` as you have countries. But I guess that you'll need to post a new question. However, before you do this, you should make a quick google search on nested lists! :-) If it does not solve your question, then post a new one!

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll try to see if I can make, otherwise I'll post another one. Thanks again, super kind!

Comment: Good luck with it!

Comment: Gave up! just posted a new one :D